# "Suspicious Activity Might Have been Detected" malware in Safari or other browsers

Tags: macos, ios, safari

Did you navigate to a page that produced a popup that says (among other things)...

**Suspicious Activity Might Have been Detected**

...and then asks you to call a toll free number? As you might have guessed, this is a scam, and seems to be going around for a while now. It happens on iOS and MacOS, and in different browsers.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution on iOS/Safari:

1. Close Safari
2. Open Settings
3. Look for the Safari settings, click it
4. Click Advanced (at the bottom)
5. There is a setting for JavaScript, turn it off
6. Close Settings
7. Open Safari
8. Close the message box if it is still open
9. Click on the "show me all the web pages" icon in the lower right (whatever it's called)
10. Close the page in question
11. Go back to Settings and turn JavaScript back on

All done!

Answer (score 1):

I simply just cleared my history and it went away for me (iPhone user)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution on MacOS/Safari:

1. In the effected Safari, select Settings from the Safari menu
2. Click on Security
3. Click on the "Enable JavaScript" checkbox to **turn it off**
4. Close the message box, if it is still open
5. Close the page that caused the pop-up
6. Go back to Settings and turn JavaScript back on

All done!